# msysgit - how do I use gitk to search for string in commit ignoring case

Tags: git, msysgit, gitk

I'm sure this question seems really simple. I have a git repository and I am reviewing it in gitk. There is an option to:

Find <kbd>Next</kbd> <kbd>prev</kbd> commit adding/removing string: *some string* <kbd>IgnCase</kbd> <kbd>All fields</kbd>

There are commits that contain *Some String* (exactly as I just cased it) and if I search for it exactly as cased gitk will show the matches. However if I search as I did above using *some string* then there are no matches. Maybe it's late and I'm tired but why doesn't that work? Does anyone here use msysgit? I'm using git version 1.7.11.msysgit.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gitk internally calls `git diff-tree -S<string>` in that case, which performs a case sensitive search. In fact, `git diff-tree` seems to even accept a (somewhat undocumented) "-i" option to ignore the case, but gitk does not make use of that. In short, it's a bug in gitk as it should either disable "IgnCase" when searching added / removed strings or make use of "-i".